# XML parsing In Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, xml-parsing

I want to parse the XML which [I got from this url](http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=,,,50500000,30500000)

and I am doing parsing like this:

```
connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(_url);
//Build Documents Based on the File
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
builder.isValidating();
Document document = builder.parse(connection.openInputStream());
Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
rootElement.normalize();
NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName("current_conditions");
int check = list.getLength();
for(int i=0;i < check; i++){
    //NodeList children = list.item(i).getChildNodes();
    Node children = list.item(i).getFirstChild();
    String conditionData = new String();
    if (children.getNodeType()!= Node.TEXT_NODE){
        NamedNodeMap child = children.getAttributes();
        if(child.getNamedItem("data")!=null){
            conditionData = child.getNamedItem("data").getNodeValue();
            System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++"+conditionData);
        }
    }           
}
                
//displayNode( rootElement, 0 );
                
}catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    System.err.println("++++++++++++++++++"+e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: What is your problem here? Got any exception?

Comment: its value is coming null i dont get any attributre's value can you dig into the code and tell me whether i am doing mistake

Answer (score 1):

Your list.item(i) may have no childs so children will be null. Anyway, try to use parser from bb samples. Here is its code: [XMLDemo code](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/xml-parser/td-p/970995)

Comment: i had done it by that it only giving me the tag name only but i dont get any attribute value can you step in the code and tell me whether i am doing mistake .. .....